# Issue when convert string to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, objective-c++

I want to covert C++ string to `NSString` to use in iOS app.

But sometimes the result is nil for C++ string with strange suffix format.

*For example: a C++ string "but in fact it turned out to be you!$\211/" will produce nil after convert to `NSString`.*

```
mainFile.open(filePath, std::ios::binary);
mainFile.seekg(current_offset);
char buffer[size]; 
mainFile.read(buffer, sizeof buffer);
string tempString = string(buffer)
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithCString:tempString.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When `cout << tempString` I still read the string content with a strange code suffix, but it produces nil after convert to `NSString`

**Anyone know how to fix this?**

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you how to fix code you haven't shared with us? We don't know how you're trying to convert it or what the code is doing. Please edit your post and include a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Every string has number code at the end will produce nil. In my example, strange code is: \211  I read the original string from binary file.

Comment: Oh FFS! Your _source code_. Reduce your _source code_ to an MCVE and include it in your post. Telling us what character code is getting inserted in your stirngs is next to useless at this point.

Comment: I provided the source code.

Comment: @abelhoang: That source code can't be run by readers. Use a literal as data, instead of reading it from a file. Also, be clear about the programming language, please. It looks like a mix of C++ and Objective C? I have never used Objective C (not a Mac person) so I don't know. But it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with the C++ portion at all?

```
NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/some/file.txt";
NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];

[input seekToOffset:current_offset];

NSData *bytes = [input readDataOfLength:size];
if (bytes)
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to read from file");
}
```

If `str` is `nil`, then it means that the data is not encoded as UTF8, so you need to find what encoding your data is actually in. If it came from a Windows computer, try `NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding` or `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`.

Comment: Thanks, I use C++ to write a lib that uses for Android also. the lib read  some hundred thousands of records, so I think C++ is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The code is specifying the encoding `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but the string has a byte value that is not a valid UTF-8 character. Pick an encoding that matches the string.

Try an encoding such as `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`:

> 8-bit ISO Latin 1 encoding.

`NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` might be another encoding to consider if you are coming from a Mac environment.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to remove invalid character before covert it ?. Because I can't use NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, it produce unreadable text mixed with readable text.

Comment: Sure,remove all characters that have the high bit set, the they will by OK for `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. But you will be loosing text. Try all the encodings, maybe one of them will work. I just went through this converting Fortran and C++ code that had a Mac copyright symbol in it. You can also use BBEdit and the "Zap Gremlins" command.